# Is there a way to add all the custom fields of several SObjects into the changeset?

Tags: change-set

We have developed a new feature which includes several objects and a ton of new fields. I am wondering if there is a method to put every custom field of those sobjects into changeset? Otherwise I have to go through them one by one which is quite painful.

Comment: I think you can add the custom objects first and then by 'View/Add Dependencies' you can add all the fields if it is new object.

Comment: @RCS That actually answers my question. If you make it an answer I will accept that. Thank you.

Comment: added the same in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the custom objects first and then by `View/Add Dependencies` you can add all the fields if it is new object.

Comment: Just to advise: In complex orgs this may backfire as one object definition may be linked to a very large number of components indirectly. Any lookup relationships will cause a chain relationship to other objects and their fields. Any Lightning App Builder layouts (flexipages) configured as the Org-Wide Default for the object will become dependencies too, and then bring along for the ride any custom components (including Visualforce, Lightning and Apex) that have been placed on that App Builder page.